# Using setReadTimeout in HttpURLConnection with proxy settings

Tags: java, proxy, httpurlconnection, connection-timeout

I am trying to connect to the internet with the user defined proxy settings. I have set the `setReadTimeout` to 5 seconds. If the configured proxy is not correct, then we wont be able to connect to internet and i am using the following code, but the read time out is not at all happening.

```
            URL u = new URL("http://www.google.com/");
            System.out.println("Checking internet connection availability.....");
            System.setProperty("java.net.useSystemProxies", "true");
            System.setProperty("http.proxyHost", proxyHost);
            System.setProperty("http.proxyPort", proxyPort);
            HttpURLConnection uc = (HttpURLConnection) u.openConnection();
            uc.setReadTimeout(5000);
            System.out.println("Response code : " + uc.getResponseCode());
            System.out.println("Internet connection is available.....");
```

If i run the above code, then program is keep on executing and not getting terminated in 5 seconds.

Can anybody help me out here about the problem in my code ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try also adding `uc.setConnectTimeout(5000);`

**Edit: Final solution**

Use `uc.connect();` before getting the response code.

Also, add the proxy configuration while opening the HttpURLConnection.

Like this :

```
HttpURLConnection uc = (HttpURLConnection) u.openConnection(new Proxy(Proxy.Type.HTTP, new InetSocketAddress(myProxyHost, Integer.parseInt(myProxyPort))));
```

Comment: Weird, I have a code similar to yours excepted that I'm using the proxy-vole library to handle proxy's configuration and it seems to work perfectly.

Comment: Maybe you can try using the `uc.connect();` before getting the response code?

Comment: Thanks Padrus. I have used `uc.connect()` It is working now. Also, I have also added the proxy config while opening the `HttpURLConnection` like as follows,               `HttpURLConnection uc = (HttpURLConnection) u.openConnection(new Proxy(Proxy.Type.HTTP, new InetSocketAddress(myProxyHost, Integer.parseInt(myProxyPort))));`

Comment: Nice, I'll edit my answer so maybe you can accept it and it could help other users.